# How to make an effect last for a number of rounds in a turn-based game?

Tags: java, game-development

player java text-based turn-based game (one player will make moves, followed by another), which allows one player to cast spell on another. I would like enable the spell to have an effect with a specific duration for its target.
For example, decrease the target's damage for 2 rounds. What's the better approach to do this?

```
   private void reducedamage(Hero target) {
    target.setdamage(target.damageMin/2,target.damageMax/2,5);
    System.out.println(target.name+" is crippled!\n"+target.name+"'s min damage:"+target.damageMin+"\n"+target.name+"'s max damage:"+target.damageMax);
}
```

how should i utilise the 'turn' parameter in this case?
turn refers to the number of rounds this spell should work

Comment: Your question as it's posted now is very broad, and depends on the way your game and turn based system are written. What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: im making in a way that every time a player make moves , turn+=1. but i don't know how to make the effect disappear at the round when it should disappear. code example edited

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what your design and implementation is. But suppose you have a game object, which keeps info on players, turns, active player, etc.

This object could also keep reference to sort of health credit balance of each of the players (which I'd name differently, maybe `lastingDamageRemaining` or something), which is paid off in installments, on every turn (whether opponent's, or the active player's turn, depending on your game design).

Whenever a spell is cast by a player, you increase the value of `lastingDamageRemaining` by the power of the spell, and specify the "installments" or how much each turn shall reduce.